# Asynchronous event not working when ipad iOS 9 goes in sleep mode

Tags: sleep, mode

I have some ajax call which are waiting for data asynchornously. When my iPad Air 2 with iOS 9.2 using Chrome,  goes in sleep mode the asynchronous callback is never executed.Not in sleep mode not when it comes out of sleep mode. No exception, no error. Completely vanishes. So my screen remains with old data.
Any information it is know issue/ workaround?

Futher I found this happens iOS for several other occasions also,
1. Hold the page by multiple fingers drag down.
2. Minimize the browser and maximize
3. If you have multiple tab, make your tab inactive for few sec ( approx.5 sec)

Also as i understood that every browser limits active ajax request to max 4 or 6. If this issue occurs 6 times by any of the above means then all remaining ajax request goes in queue. The only option left is to close the tab and start with new session.

Comment: How it enters sleep mode? By screen locking or by timeout?

Comment: I have a somewhat related issue with websockets which disconnects on ios-devices. Also looking for a solution.

Comment: it does not matter how it enters sleep mode. once it goes in sleep mode this issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jquery   $.ajax()  I used  $.jsonp() and it solved the issue.